# Overlapping of Buttons with canvas for mouseinput

Tags: java, user-interface, button, canvas, mouseevent

I am currently making a RPG hack and slash in java with just the standard libraries.

For these games , I had made a `CustomButton` class in an independent package that I just copy and paste in almost all of my games and then make some game-specific modifications.

This is the class::

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;

import objects.Collectable;

public final class CustomButton implements MouseListener {

    // private BufferedImage image;
    private String text = "";
    private boolean pressed = false;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Color currentColor, defaultColor, hoverColor, pressColor;
    private Point mousePoint = new Point(0, 0);
    private ButtonListener btnListener = null;
    private Canvas canvasObject;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private BufferedImage darkImage;
    private String actionCommand = "default";
    private Collectable object;

    private boolean enabled;
    /*
     * private CustomButton(Canvas canvasObject,JFrame frame) { this.x=100;
     * this.y=100; this.width=100; this.height=100;
     * 
     * canvasObject.addMouseListener(this); currentColor=new Color(255,255,255);
     * defaultColor=new Color(255,255,255); hoverColor=new Color(255,255,255);
     * pressColor=new Color(255,255,255); }
     */

    public CustomButton(int x, int y, int width, int height, Canvas canvasObject) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.canvasObject = canvasObject;
        canvasObject.addMouseListener(this);
        currentColor = Color.GREEN;
        currentColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        defaultColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        hoverColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        pressColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        enabled = true;
    }

    public CustomButton(int x, int y, int width, int height, Canvas canvasObject, BufferedImage image,
            Collectable object) {
        this.image = image;
        this.darkImage = darkenImage(image);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        canvasObject.addMouseListener(this);
        currentColor = Color.GREEN;
        currentColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        defaultColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        hoverColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        pressColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        this.canvasObject = canvasObject;
        this.object = object;

        enabled = true;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        if (image == null) {
            g.setColor(currentColor);
            if (!pressed)
                g.fillRect(this.x, this.y, width, height);
            else
                g.fill3DRect(this.x, this.y, width, height, true);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString(text, this.x + 10, this.y + 15);
        } else {
            if (enabled) {
                g.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height, null);
            } else {
                g.drawImage(darkImage, x, y, width, height, null);
            }
        }
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

    }

    public void tick() {
        mousePoint = getMouseLocation();
        changeColor();
    }

    private Point getMouseLocation() {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        try {
            x = (int) (canvasObject.getMousePosition().getX());
            y = (int) (canvasObject.getMousePosition().getY());
        } catch (NullPointerException nl) {
        }

        return new Point(x, y);
    }

    public void changeColor() {

        if (!pressed) {
            if (getBounds().contains(mousePoint))
                currentColor = hoverColor;
            else
                currentColor = defaultColor;
        } else {
            currentColor = pressColor;
        }

    }

    public void addButtonListener(ButtonListener btnListener) {
        this.btnListener = btnListener;
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (enabled) {
            if (btnListener != null) {

                if (getBounds().contains(mousePoint)) {
                    ButtonID id = ButtonID.UNDETERMINABLE;
                    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) id = ButtonID.LEFT;
                    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) id = ButtonID.RIGHT;

                    btnListener.buttonClicked(new ButtonEvent(id, object, actionCommand));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (getBounds().contains(mousePoint)) pressed = true;
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        pressed = false;
    }

    public void setActionCommand(String actionCommand) {
        this.actionCommand = actionCommand;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void setDefaultColor(Color c) {
        defaultColor = c;
    }

    public void setHoverColor(Color c) {
        hoverColor = c;
    }

    public void setPressColor(Color c) {
        pressColor = c;
    }

    public Collectable getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public void setObject(Collectable object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public void destroy() {
        canvasObject.removeMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void disable() {
        enabled = false;
    }

    public void enable() {
        enabled = true;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    private BufferedImage darkenImage(BufferedImage image) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        image = deepCopy(image);

        WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();

        for (int xx = 0; xx < width; xx++) {
            for (int yy = 0; yy < height; yy++) {
                int[] pixels = raster.getPixel(xx, yy, (int[]) null);
                pixels[0] -= 50;
                pixels[1] -= 50;
                pixels[2] -= 50;

                pixels[0] = Math.max(pixels[0], 0);
                pixels[1] = Math.max(pixels[0], 0);
                pixels[2] = Math.max(pixels[0], 0);

                raster.setPixel(xx, yy, pixels);
            }
        }
        return image;
    }

    private BufferedImage deepCopy(BufferedImage bi) {
        ColorModel cm = bi.getColorModel();
        boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
        WritableRaster raster = bi.copyData(null);
        return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
    }

}
```

As you can probably see from the `mouseClicked()` method that a event is sent to the `ButtonListener` class.The `ButtonListener` interface is also declared in the package.

This button is drawn on the canvas itself.For example, in the levelmap, there is a button in the lower-right corner, which on clicking will open the inventory.Let this button be called `btn_INV`.

Until now,I have been taking inputs for moving the player through the keyboard.But I plan to change  keyInput to mouse input where the player will move to the tile where the user clicks on.

For that I have to make a class , say`MouseInput` that implements `MouseListener`.Now the problem is that when I click `btn_INV` , not only will the button generate an event, but also, since the button is actually drawn on the canvas, the `MouseInput` class will also get an event as to the tile to which the player wants to moving.Now, I thought that when the `MouseInput` class gets a `MouseEvent`, it will check with the buttons as whenever there is a mouse click on the canvas, the buttons *always* gets informed, although it may not generate a `ButtonEvent`, as you can see from the code.But this is a rather bad method and highly inefficient.So , I want another method for this.

**NOTE :** I thought of creating another canvas for displaying the HUD and the `btn_INV` and other such buttons, but that does not really solve the issue as much as bypass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's two ways to solve this problem :

- The first will be to divide your game screen into two parts : one for the buttons, the other for the tiles, so you can test whilecatching a MouseEvent if the click is positionned on the tiles or not. Note that the tiles can be placed on a new button. This solution is easy to implement but you won't be able to place buttons on your tile's area.
- The second will be to create a "ButtonManager". Your game class will have this button manager that will listen for mouse event and send then to the buttons. Buttons won't listen directly to this event. They will say one after one if the click is on their bounds and if no button have been fired it means that the click occured on the tiles. This method is little bit more difficult to implement but allows you to create a priority beetween buttons and so buttons would be able to have thei bounds intersecting !

Hope it helped you !

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, concepts like button listeners are used in applications, not games.

Games generally work with a game loop which will have an update and a draw phase. During the update phase, user input is caught (well... more checked than caught, but I'll get to that in a moment) and interpreted.

So you'd just have one big mouse listener that would then check to see which button might be pressed or if the mouse is within the game area so the character should get the move command.

Of course technically that mouse listener shouldn't directly do anything, as it is bound to the swing thread. It should just change some variables (like: "left mouse button is down, position is x, y") that will then be checked in your update phase, which will then actually work with it. That way, you're no longer dependant on the swing thread (which isn't ideal for games anyway) and - almost as important - your game logic is completely predictable.

However, you'd still have to make sure your draw method gets called regularly and actually paints what and when you want it to paint. That's besides the question though, so I won't go into more detail on it.

Keep in mind that even swing isn't just some magical construct. When the mouse is clicked, swing will also iterate through all elements you have and see if one of them should get an event. If you write your own Buttons, that's what you're gonna have to do, too.

Giving each button it's own Mouse Listener will only get confusing the bigger your game gets. It will also destroy your game loop as mouse events can be thrown and caught at any time regardless of what you're doing at the moment. If your game logic happens in a seperate thread from swing (which it should), it's even possible that you get an event while you're processing something. Which will screw up your result.

This may also lead to a couple of very odd one-time errors that you don't understand and can't reproduce. So be very careful with that.

Comment: Thank you for your time and advise.I will change my a=program accordingly as what you have mentioned is valid.But one thing I would say is that the `btn_INV` only changes the `GameState` so it does not matter if I call that method while executing some other update on the main game thread.However what you said about the `MouseListener` thread just creating some "ActionCommands" is a good point and I will try to implement it.Thanks.